# TypeError: insertionSort() got an unexpected keyword argument 'numberList'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

i am doing my assigment in python i need to creat function for insertion sort which take input in float and do insertion and also do print list of sorting after every single index is sorted  please dont delete post i am newbe and dont understand other solution guide me please
i need to input exactly name

```
insertionSort(numberList=[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4])
```

my function is

```
def insertionSort(intList):
    n = len(intList)
    for i in range(0, n-1):

        kMin = i
    for k in range(i+1, n):
        if (intList[k] < intList[kMin]):
            kMin = k

    if (kMin != i):
        temp = intList[i]
        intList[i] = intList[kMin]
        intList[kMin] = temp
```

my output need to be exactly like this

```
**round 1 start: [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]↩

round 1 end: [2.2, 1.1, 3.3, 4.4]↩

round 2 start: [2.2, 1.1, 3.3, 4.4]↩

round 2 end: [3.3, 2.2, 1.1, 4.4]↩
round 3 start: [3.3, 2.2, 1.1, 4.4]↩
round 3 end: [4.4, 3.3, 2.2, 1.1]**
```

Comment: Where is insertion sort?

Comment: your function name is `selectionSort` you are calling `insertionSort`?

Comment: sorry that was just wrong copy i have edited

Comment: You can't call the function like that. Create the list first. Then insert the name of the list. Or forget about the name and insert the list.

Comment: my teacher have asked me to do exactly like that

Comment: then change `intList` to `numberList` in the function definition

Comment: and how can i print *round 1 start: and  round 2 end: after  and before each index is sorted

Comment: Sounds like another question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say `insertionSort(numberList=[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4])`, but the definition of `insertionSort` expects a parameter named `intList`. Either change the name you pass to match the prototype:

```
insertionSort(intList=[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4])
```

change the definition to use the better name (since it clearly works on `float`):

```
def insertionSort(numberList):  # And change all uses inside the function to numberList
```

or just have the caller pass positionally so the name doesn't matter:

```
insertionSort([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4])
```

Comment: and how can i print *round 1 start: and round 2 end: after and before each index is sorted

Comment: Sounds like another question!

Comment: yes can you guide please

Comment: @LuckyBhi: The indentation looks wrong (pretty sure the whole body of the function should be indented under that first `for` loop), but basically you'd just add `print("round", i + 1, "start:", numberList)` (or `intList`) as the first line of the outer `for` loop, and a similar line as the last line of the `for` loop.